# C# - слишком большие отступы в консоли

Tags: c#

делаю некое подобия мессенджера, вот код сервера:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 25565));
            socket.Listen(5);
            Socket client = socket.Accept();

            while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                client.Receive(buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Когда сервер получает пакет и выводит его, то расстояние между каждых выводов: 7 строк.

Comment: `Trim` пробовали использовать?

Comment: @And Не работает.

Comment: Сделайте например маркер начала передачи и отсекайте все лишнее до него. Или передавайте данные в формате например JSON.

Comment: А вы уверены, что это пустые строки? По пробуйте в какой нибудь `Notepad` с консоли вставить и глянуть, и суда тоже вывод пришлите и как пользовались тримом?

Comment: Подойдём к проблеме с другой стороны. А как вы посылаете данные? Там тоже кодировка ASCII? Почему не юникод?

Comment: Метод `Receive` возвращает количество полученных байтов. Буфер может быть заполнен не полностью. Поэтому нужно использовать перегрузку метода `Encoding..GetString`, принимающую размер данных.

Comment: Кстати, если с той стороны будет послан большой текст, то он не влезет в буфер длиной 1024 байта и его нужно считывать в цикле, накапливая куски, пока не придёт всё. И лишь затем отправлять в `GetString`. Иначе получите мусор.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov напишите решение с получением длины из `Receive` и передачей длины в `Encoding..GetString` в ответ, оно правильное. Коментарии не для ответов, а для дополнительных вопросов, кмк.